# Cartesian/Multiple records based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables, let's call them PERSONS and PGROUP

```
create table persons(
id number(20),
name varchar2(30),
group_id number(30),
cnt number(2)
);

create table pgroup(
id number(20),
amount number(20));

insert into persons values(1,'name1',1,1);
insert into persons values(2,'name2',1,1 );
insert into persons values(3,'name3',1,1 );
insert into persons values(4,'name4',1,3 );
insert into persons values(5,'name5',null,5 );
insert into persons values(6,'name6',null,6 );
insert into persons values(7,'name7',null,7 );
insert into persons values(8,'name8',null,8 );
insert into persons values(9,'name9',null,9 );

insert into pgroup values(1,20000);
insert into pgroup values(2,12345);
```

Record in table persons could have reference to pgroup (`persons.group_id = pgroup.id`) but sometimes there are not any keys. In this scenario (`persons.group_id is null`) that person "belong" to every group so I have to propagate ("cartesian") them through these two groups.

With that, I can handle - one select to connect these records, which have keys, and union with cartesian.
But what I can not figure out is how to duplicate them based on column `persons.cnt`.

F.E.:

person 'name9' has cnt = 9:

- I need to put 9 records of him, in 2 groups,
- 9 records in 1 group should have amt = 20000
- another 9 records in group 2 should have amt = 12345;

so 1st question - Is this duplication could be done in SQL? 
2nd - Do all cases I describe here could be done in ONE QUERY (avoid union)?

Comment: Sounds like you're after a [cross join](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-cross-join/) (although what you're trying to do seems odd).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query is doing the job:

```sql
-- Here is your sample data:
WITH persons (id, name, group_id, cnt) as 
   (select 1,'name1',1,1    from dual union all
    select 2,'name2',1,1    from dual union all
    select 3,'name3',1,1    from dual union all
    select 4,'name4',1,3    from dual union all
    select 5,'name5',null,5 from dual union all
    select 6,'name6',null,6 from dual union all
    select 7,'name7',null,7 from dual union all
    select 8,'name8',null,8 from dual union all
    select 9,'name9',null,9 from dual)
   , pgroup (id,amount) as
   (select 1,20000 from dual union all
    select 2,12345 from dual)
-- As cnt is number(2) it's < 100, the following query get's all number between 1 and 99
   , cnt as (select level cnt from dual connect by level < 100) 
SELECT p.id
     , p.name
     , g.id group_id 
     , c.cnt
     , g.amount
  FROM persons p
  JOIN cnt c
    ON c.cnt <= p.cnt -- Get the duplicate records
  join pgroup g
    ON g.id = p.group_id
    OR p.group_id is NULL -- Cartesian product if group_id is null
```

The columns `g.id` and `c.cnt` are only there to show that the correct number of duplicates and the cartesian product work, you might want to select the corresponding values of table `persons` instead.